# "Other" Class in Stanford NLP Classifier for lines that are not related to ANY of the Trained Classes

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm using the Stanford NLP just fine.
I made a train file with all my classes.
and it identifies the test lines just fine.
BUT what if I have an Other line (that is not of any of the Classes I've trained it).
Can I ask the algorithm to return null etc. when the line is not recognized with any of the Classes?
If not, what/How do you recommend that I should create an "Other" Class with "other" lines.. but that could be infinite.
Thanks, Aryeh.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, yes, you should create an "Other" / `O` class to capture all "null" labels. This is the standard in e.g. NER, where the majority of the tokens in the corpus receive an `O` label (indicating no named entity label).

Comment: Thanks.
How Is it suggested to create this (infinite) "Other" Class?

Comment: Mark the class of the "other" tokens as `O` in your training data. I don't believe you need to provide any special directives, etc.